# Notice Period and Conflict of Interest

Tags: conflict-of-interest

If an employee resigns due to a conflict of interest (that is, to prevent a conflict of interest), can the employee engage in activity excluded by the conflict of interest rules during the notice period?

The employer had the option of granting "gardening leave" but did not consider the conflict of interest to be so serious as to warrant that.  The employee is still on their notice period, and the conflict of interest rule prohibits outside work (even in the employee's own time, as in this case).

Comment: Since they didn't garden leave them, are they still actually working the notice period? This is very unclear

Comment: Theoretical questions don't work well here. Are you the employee, a representative of the employer, or someone else?

Comment: Philip Kendall, it has been my experience that there is a sizeable group of answerers that have a bias against the questioner when providing their answer - they will not give an objective answer.  Whether I am the employee or the employer should be irrelevant - I want an answer from an objective observer, not legal advice.  The fact that you think this is relevant indicates you are one such biased answerer.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever made the "conflict of interest rules" you refer to, would be the best person to ask.

- If it's actual *laws*, you may want to consult a lawyer.
- If it is a company policy, you should consult a company spokesperson, maybe your manager or HR.
- If it is something in *your* business side that has those rules, you should consult *that* entity.

We cannot really help you in practice, since we don't know the actual rules you mentioned.

Comment: I am not seeking legal advice here.  In the country where this occurred, the conflict of interest rule would be legally unenforceable in the circumstances.  This is essentially a question of ethics and what is considered normal professional behaviour.